# Unable to install the TestNG plugin in eclipse

Tags: testng

Getting below error while installing **TestNG**:

[image]

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Is it a maven project? 
Try to add testNG jar file or dependency using this link https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.7

Answer (score 3):

This error is receiving due to incorrect URL. Please add correct URL to add TestNG Plugin for eclipse.

**http://beust.com/eclipse** instead brust.com.

For more details and steps you can [visit this site.](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/)

Comment: Good catch Bharat! :)